# ElasticSearch/Solr - Synonyms for a product site?

Tags: python, django, solr, elasticsearch

I'm trying to setup a synonym database for ElasticSearch. I believe Solr uses the same synonym format.

The web application I'm working on is a Python/Django based electronics product site.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html

You can use SOLR format or [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) format.

Or do I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Thanks yes, unfortunately I can't find any good synonym database which I could use. Also product sites use special "synonyms" such as acronyms e.g. Solid State Drive => SSD